# Solve a first-order nonlinear ordinary differential equation (boundary value problem)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, definite-integrals, boundary-value-problem

I have been trying to solve the following boundary value problem:
$$(x^2-36)(y')^2-2xyy'+y^2-36=0$$
Given the conditions $y(0)=6$ and $y(10)=0$, where $y(x)$ is continuously twice differentiable on $[0,10]$.
The requirement is not really to solve the problem itself, but to find
$$\int_{0}^{10}y(x)dx$$
I have almost found the answer, but got stuck. My idea was to solve for $y$ and not for $y'$:
$$y=xy'\pm6\sqrt{(y')^2+1}$$
And then to directly integrate this expression. Finally, I ended up with:
$$\int_{0}^{10}y(x)dx=\pm3\int_{0}^{10}\left(\sqrt{(y')^2+1}\right)dx$$
But I do not understand how to solve the integral on the right, I have tried many substitutions, but they led nowhere. This leads me to believe that my overall idea to solve for $y$ was a mistake, but I am not sure. I have tried solving for $y'$ and for $x$, but this did not help either. I would appreciate any suggestions on how to solve the problem.

Comment: Your first order ODE requires only one boundary condition.

Comment: For a Clairaut equation, it is possible to switch branches from a regular solution to the singular one and then back to a different regular solution. So there is some flexibility. But at the branching points the piecewise solution will not be continuous in the second derivative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the derivative of the equation to the set of knowledge
$$
[2y'(x^2-36)-2xy]y''=0
$$
This means that solutions can have segments where they are linear,
$$
y=Cx+D,
$$
where the constants may be connected via the original equation,
and other segments where
$$
\frac{y'}{y}=\frac{x}{x^2-36}\implies y^2=C(x^2-36),
$$
where again $C$ might be bound by the original equation.

Insert these formulas and solve for the constants. Then try to find the correct combination of such pieces to satisfy the boundary condition. It might not be possible to get an everywhere continuous second derivative.

---

That the derivative factors so well is related to the fact that the reduction of the first equation via quadratic equation solution formula results in Clairaut equations.